# How to build multiple charts with different y-axis in same graph (Amcharts)

Tags: javascript, html, reporting, amcharts

I'm using Amcharts and I want to build something like [this](https://www.amcharts.com/demos-v3/intraday-data-v3/). But my x-axis is not in date format it is numeric (1,2,3,4..). Two questions

1. Can I use the above chart but with the numerical axis. I have tried but not able to make it work with the numerical axis.
2. Can I use other serial charts to create multiple y-axis charts with in the same chart where I have successfully replaced the date axis with the numeric axis
3. Also if there are any D3 alternatives available please mention.

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce the demo ?

Comment: I dont know if I am wrong, but every demo of amcharts are using date X-axis, I am not sure amcharts allow otherwise.

Comment: Sure, just add ValueAxis to both xAxes and yAxes. There are a lot of demos with both numeric axes: http://www.amcharts.com/demos/#xy-bubble